# Django Rest Framework and Djongo: serializer create method returns an object with incorrect _id

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, djongo

I have following Djongo model:

```
from djongo import models

class Feedback(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(blank=False)
    datetimestmp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have following serializer for the model above:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Feedback

class FeedbackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ["datetimestmp", "_id"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        obj = super().create(validated_data)
        print(obj._id)
        return obj
```

When I'm sending POST request to create a Feedback entry inside DB wrong id gets printed to the console:

```
curl -X POST -H "Conte-Type: application/json" -d '{"title": "Example Title", "text": "Example Text"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/feedbacks
```

results in `24` being printed to the server console instead of real ObjectId from MongoDB: `ObjectId("61f85ecbb0804f215c127c30")`.

Is there a way to resolve this issue? Thank you

Comment: It should be `super().create(**validated_data)` and in your curl data you have to pass `_id` since you are defining custom id.

Comment: ObjectIdField in Djongo inherits from AutoField and supposed to be auto-generated.

Comment: If I try to unpack validated_data I get unexpected argument error